# The thread was interrupted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am using this code to update database with new values. But it return message *The thread was interrupted*. What does it mean? What is wrong with my code?

```
 Dim connStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DeskriptivaConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString()
    Dim txtName As Object = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtName"), TextBox)
    Dim txtLastName As Object = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox)
    Dim txtInfo As Object = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtInfo"), TextBox)
    Dim txtCity As Object = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtCity"), TextBox)
    Dim txtPrize As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtPrize"), TextBox)
    Dim txtPhone As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtPhone"), TextBox)
    Dim txtMail As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView1.FindControl("txtMail"), TextBox)


    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Profiles SET @Name = Name, @LastName = LastName, @Info = Info, @City = City, @Prize = Prize, @Phone = Phone, @Mail = Mail WHERE (UserName = @UserName)"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Info", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = MakeLink(HtmlRemoval.StripTagsCharArray(txtInfo.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prize", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPrize.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhone.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mail", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMail.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Context.User.Identity.Name

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Profil/"))
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Profil/"), false)` with `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` instead of `Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Profil/"))`

check [Correct use of System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx) blog post for more information

and also your sql parameters @ symbol is in wrong place. change as below

`UPDATE Profiles SET
Name = @Name, LastName
= @LastName, Info =
@Info, City = @City,
Prize = @Prize, Phone
= @Phone, Mail = @Mail
WHERE (UserName =
@UserName)`

Comment: Thanks, that solved that problem. But data still don't update in database. Could you check the code above again please, because the code works in other applications, but doesn't work now.